# BreezeJS - binding to all entities

Tags: angularjs, breeze

My app is based on notifications from the server, using SignalR I am getting the entities and adding them using

```
manager.createEntity(entityType, entity, breeze.EntityState.Unchanged);
```

The UI is based on Angular grid which is bind to all the entities of certain type, how ever when I am adding new entity the grid isn't being updated, my assumption was that I am bind to the cache and not other collection. Same issue when I am removing entity

Comment: I don't know how you are binding to a list of entities but assuming that it is a navigation property of a parent entity it should be updated when that property is updated, provided you aren't using sorting directly in the UI (at which point the binding may not update) but if that is not the case have you tried creating the entity and chaining on to the method `.entityAspect.acceptChanges()` instead of creating it with state unchanged?

Comment: i am binding using ng-repeat on the collection, this is the whole concept. I am not using navigation properties. when I am updating a property of one of the entities all is good, just not when adding/removing entity. I am creating it with state unchanged cause I dont want that the manager will go to the server to create new entity

Comment: Collection of what?  You probably ran a query at some time and the results were what you bound to.  If you wish to add another item to that collection you need to have some way to reference the collection, Breeze knows nothing of it more than likely.

Comment: well according to the documentation and code -->getEntities -  This method can be used to get all of the entities within an EntityManager

Comment: meaning that you get the reference to the real collection that holds the entities of a certain type

Comment: No, you get all of the entities but that is simply a collection as of that moment in time.  If you wanted to create an entity to hold the collection of all the entities you have it would update when entities were added to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As @PWKad pointed out in the comments above, the `getEntities` function builds an array each time it is called, returning the entities from its cache that match the parameters.  The resulting array won't be updated when the cache changes.

In your case, you should store the array that's returned by getEntities, then add each new entity to it after that:

```
scope.gridList = manager.getEntities(entityType);
// ... then later:
scope.gridList.push(manager.createEntity(entityType, entity, breeze.EntityState.Unchanged));
```